# Modify image of primefaces rowToggler

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I need to modify the image of primefaces rowToggler. This is what I'm trying in the css file:

```
.ui-datatable .ui-row-toggler {
   cursor: pointer;
   background-image: url("/resources/images/expand.jpg") ; 
}
```

I have also tried changing the url to /images/expand.jpg, images/expand.jpg and simply expand.jpg. But none of them find the image.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

This is an old thread: adding an answer in case anyone else finds this on Google.  The problem comes from the fact that the class used for adding the icon is hardcoded (see [the source code](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/trunk/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/rowtoggler/RowTogglerRenderer.java?r=3432)) to be the class `ui-icon-circle-triangle-e` when the row is collapsed, and `ui-icon-circle-triangle-s` when the row is expanded.  So the way to do this is to override the definitions of those classes in your style sheet.  Here is what worked for me:

```
.ui-icon-circle-triangle-e {
    background-image: url('../images/triangleRight.png') !important;
    background-position: 0px 0px;   
}

.ui-icon-circle-triangle-s {
    background-image: url('../images/triangleDown.png') !important;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
```

The defaults looked too much like simple bullet points - users were overlooking that they were clickable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are putting your images inside the `resources` folder of your Project, you should access it like this:

```
.ui-datatable .ui-row-toggler {
   cursor: pointer;
   background-image: url("../javax.faces.resource/expand.jpg.xhtml?ln=images/") ; 
}
```

The *magical formula* should be

```
../javax.faces.resource/<file-name>.xhtml?ln=<path-to-the-folder>/
```

So if your image is at `/resources/car/bmw/series7.jpg`, you should access it with `../javax.faces.resource/series7.jpg.xhtml?ln=car/bmw/`

Comment: may not always work depending on where the current page is located. If its at "a/b/c/d.jsf" then this won't work.

Comment: :P yeah, he may need to change based on the level. But he should be able to get the general idea with it

Comment: Actually I think this issue is specific to the rowToggler. When I look at the source I can't find the expand.jpg regardless of the url I'm specifying. Instead this is what is printed in the html: <span class="ui-row-toggler ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e">

Comment: Go to the your earlier question, I did tell you that rowToggler has an attribute to change its style class. You should use it

Comment: Where do you find this attribute? Is it style, or styleClass? I tried looking for the tag reference but it's not mentioned there.

Comment: Tried it like this: <p:rowToggler class="togImg" rendered="#{bean.something}"/> It's causing a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Component property class is not writable

Comment: @user1037343 :P My bad. You shouldn't use that tag. CSS is the right way. Btw, you should type the the image's URL in the browser's address bar to make sure you got the right path first.

Comment: Nothing seems to work. If anyone wants to give it a shot, great. But basically I don't think the toggler image can be changed.

Answer (score 1):

With the information you provided, its most likely because you have an app running on "localhost/APP_NAME/", and when you do "/resources/..." it points to "localhost/resources/..." which doesn't exist (it should resolve to "localhost/APP_NAME/resources/...".

Try this instead of url (its JSF specific)

```
url("#{resource['images:expand.jpg']}")
```

Comment: Actually I think this issue is specific to the rowToggler. When I look at the source I can't find the expand.jpg regardless of the url I'm specifying. Instead this is what is printed in the html: <span class="ui-row-toggler ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e">

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
        $(document).on("click", ".ui-icon-circle-triangle-e", function() {
            $(this).css({
                background: 'url(#{request.contextPath}/images/data/silm.gif)'
            });

        });
    /*]]>*/
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .ui-datatable .ui-row-toggler {
            cursor: pointer;
            background: url(#{request.contextPath}/images/data/eklem.gif) ; 
        } 
    </style>
```