# How to change PrimeNG datatable expander icon

Tags: css, angular, primeng-datatable

I am using PrimeNG datatable for my usage. Below is my code:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="alerts" [expandableRows]="true" [expandedRows]="expandedItems" #dt>
 <p-column expander="true"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

How can I change the default icon for the row expander ?

Comment: Could this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/8790095/5468463

Answer (score 0):

You can override your component CSS like that :

```
::ng-deep .fa-chevron-circle-right::before {
  content: "\f055";
  color: green;
}

::ng-deep .fa-chevron-circle-down::before {
  content: "\f056";
}
```

See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sff45i)